# How to set a maximum vertical scroll position to scroll panel in gwt?

Tags: ipad, gwt, scroll

I am using ScrollPanel in GWT 2.4 and I am unable to set the maximum vertical scroll position, as a result of which, the scrolling happens pretty fast.

The scroll momentum takes me to the end of the content in a matter of a couple of seconds. Please note that I have lots of data inside the ScrollPanel (Only text though...). If I tweak the momentum a bit, the scroll either stops abruptly or doesn't look like native scrolling.

I am viewing my application in ipad(ios7). I tried using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` but that gives me a flicker that I can't get rid of even after using `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` or `-wekit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` or a combination of both. On top of it, the scroll seems unresponsive and scroll occurs approximately 500ms after the touch end event has occured.

Is there a way to restrict the maximum no.of pixels the panel can scroll and yet make it look pleasing. Also can someone tell me why there is a delay for scroll?